# Not mapping correctly <InputNumber TValue="decimal"

Tags: decimal, blazor-webassembly, decimalformat, .net-8.0, blazor-editform

I have <EditForm...> and a decimal input field. Problem is that I have 10,00 value in variable, but Blazor converts it to 10.0000 (trailing zeroes are not a problem). When I post the form over API it is saved as 100000.

I know the issue is somewhere in localization and I have implemented every suggestion by BingChat, Github Copilot, and lastly from learn.Microsoft.com

```
<InputNumber TValue="decimal" @bind-Value="@item.Quantity" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
```

I also know that my browser is set to English(UK), and that is not technically correct, as my application uses hr-HR, but I need the app working no matter the browser settings.

I am on .net 8 and using (mostly) WebAssembly.

**EDIT - Info update**

Problematic <InputNumber...> inside a Bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 rounded-3 border-danger border fs-3 text-center" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ProducedQuantity-@item.FactoryOrderItemId">
    @item.Quantity.RoundToString()
</div>
<div class="clearix"></div>

//////////////////////////////
///  #ProducedQuantity-@orderItemId
//////////////////////////////
<div class="modal fade" id="ProducedQuantity-@item.FactoryOrderItemId" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ProducedQuantityLabel-@item.FactoryOrderItemId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="ProducedQuantityLabel-@item.FactoryOrderItemId">
                    @Frontend.ProducedQuantity
                </h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-20 col-md-20  align-content-center text-center">
                        @item.ProductName
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ConnectedName))
                        {
                            <span class="text-warning"><i class="bi bi-flower3"></i></span>
                            <span>@item.ConnectedName</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-20 col-md-20">
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" type="button" @onclick="(() => FactoryOrderItemQuantityMinus(item))"><i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i></button>

                            <InputNumber TValue="decimal" @bind-Value="@item.Quantity" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                            
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" type="button" @onclick="(() => FactoryOrderItemQuantityPlus(item))"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i></button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 align-content-center text-center">
                        <button type="button" @onclick="(() => UpdateProducedQuantity(item))" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                            @Frontend.Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Function called when Saving (inside razor page):

```
private async Task UpdateProducedQuantity(FactoryOrderItemListVM item)
{
    await _factory.UpdateProducedQuantity(item.FactoryOrderItemId, item.Quantity);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Service implementation that makes request from webassembly to server api:

```
public async Task UpdateProducedQuantity(int FactoryOrderItemId, decimal Quantity)
{
    if(FactoryOrderItemId > 0)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync($"api/Factory/UpdateProducedQuantity/{FactoryOrderItemId}/{Quantity}", null);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _sys.ToastSuccess();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await _sys.ToastErrorAsync(response);
            return;
        }
    }
    _sys.ToastError(Errors.ParameterNotValid);
    return;
}
```

The request sent to api:

```
https://localhost:7226/api/Factory/UpdateProducedQuantity/50/10,0000
```

And api controller that handles request. Here the value ends up as 100000, and should be 10,0000:

```
[HttpPut("UpdateProducedQuantity/{FactoryOrderItemId}/{Quantity}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateProducedQuantity(int FactoryOrderItemId, decimal Quantity)
{
    try
    {
        if (FactoryOrderItemId > 0)
        {
            await _factory.UpdateProducedQuantityAsync(FactoryOrderItemId, Quantity);
            _logger.LogDebug("UpdateProducedQuantity: {@FactoryOrderItemId} {@Quantity}", FactoryOrderItemId, Quantity);
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(Errors.ParameterNotValid);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Exception: {@ex}", ex);
        return StatusCode(500, Errors.FactoryUpdateProducedQuantity);
    }
}
```

[image: How thin looks]

Note that values below the modal have decimal coma (,) and in  it is decimal point (.)

And this I use to display decimal values:

```
public static string RoundToString(this decimal Val)
{
    decimal roundedValue = Math.Round(Val, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return roundedValue.ToString("0.00");
}
```

Comment: You are not providing the necessary information.  To where is the value going?  What is it when it goes out?  What type is the API expecting?  Are you sending out the data as a JSON request, or as a URL parameter?  More info plz

Comment: I have resolved the issue by changing api call to HttpPost, and have put data in model and serialized the object before sending it. But I am still curious why was mapping not correct the other way.

Comment: Oh now I see your query.  Yeah, as far as I know, the comma "," is a reserved character, and cannot be used in a URL request.  I think serializing and deserializing your data is a much better procedure anyway.